# Create new dataframe using unique values in one column, values in another column becoming new columns, summing values from a third column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

If I have a dataFrame with columns "id", "name" and "result" (which is booleans) (with some other columns not needed), how can I most elegantly make a new dataframe with

- unique values of "id" becoming rows in the dataframe

and "name"s as columns, summing the "results" column (which is thus the number of   Trues for this combo of id & name)

Using my dataframe df containing "id", "name" and "result" I tried:

df_summary = df.groupby(['id', 'name'])['result'].sum()

which sort of works but is a series, so I then did

df_summary = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['id', 'name'])['result'].sum())

which outputs a bit nicer as a dataframe, but I end up of course with a table looking like this

| id | name | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | name1 | ### |
| (blank) | name2 | ### |
| (blank) | name3 | ### |
| ... | ... | ### |
| id2 | name1 | ### |
| (blank) | name2 | ### |
| (blank) | name3 | ### |
| ... | ... | ### |

etc (# = the sum since Trues count as 1s)

what I ideally want is a table like this

| "id" | name1 | name2 | name3 | etc | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | ### | ### | ### | ### | ### |
| id2 | ### | ### | ### | ### | ### |
| id3 | ### | ### | ### | ### | ### |

so the unique ids in the left column, but then the names become columns which show the sum according to the group (id, name), and then at the end a sum of all those values

Right now the set of "names" is the same for each ID but I can't guarantee thats always the case.

Answer (score 1):

Add [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df_summary = (df.groupby(['id', 'name'])['result']
                .sum()
                .unstack(fill_value=0)
                .assign(total = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
```

Or [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df_summary = (df.pivot_table(index='id', 
                             columns='name', 
                             values='result', 
                             aggfunc='sum', 
                             fill_value=0)
                .assign(total = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this, quicker reply than it took me to edit the question to format the tables haha